# How to capture execution plan from sql profiler for filtered queries only

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, profiler

Using sql profiler, we trace all slow queries (filter on duration/reads) to see where we can optimise.
Events used:

- RPC:Completed
- SQL:BatchCompleted

Filter on Duration.

If I add the event ShowPlan XML, then I cannot filter on the duration of the underlying query, creating a huge load as hundreds/thousands of queries arrive each second

How to only capture the execution plan for the entries that match the filter duration/reads of the captured queries from the other events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to stop using Profiler and go to Extended Events. The [query_post_execution_showplan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/showplan-xml-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15) event has duration built right in and you can use that to filter capture quite neatly. Here's a simple example:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION ExecPlansDuration
ON SERVER
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.query_post_execution_showplan
    (WHERE ([duration] > (10000)))
    ADD TARGET package0.event_file
    (SET filename = N'ExecPlansDuration');
```

Just know that capturing plans can be very expensive.